# Haskell :: Recursion for List of Tuples

Tags: haskell, recursion, tuples

I am mapping a tuple and managed to make it work for a single tuple (a, a). But when I've changed the tuple to `[[(a, a)]]`, then it says that "couldn't match the expected type of `[(a, a)]` with `(a, a)`.

```
    mapTuple :: (a -> b) -> [[(a, a)]] -> [(b, b)]
    mapTuple f [] = []
    mapTuple f ((a1, a2) : xs) = (f a1, f a2) : mapTuple f xs

    myfunc :: Int -> Int
    myfunc xk = xk + 1


    myTup = [[(1,2),(5,6),(9,10)]] :: [[(Int, Int)]]
    test = mapTuple myfunc myTup
```

Couldn't break the error yet. I am missing something here. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Well that's logical isn't it?

Comment: What result do you want to get if the input is `[[(1,1),(2,2)],[(3,3)]]`?

Comment: It should be `[[(2,2),(3,3)],[(4,4)]]`

Comment: Do you want to flatten the input list or not? The function you've just described has type `(a -> b) -> [[(a, a)]] -> [[(b, b)]]`.

Comment: `[[(2,2),(3,3)],[(4,4)]]` is of a wrong type. You wanted  `[(b, b)]` but it is of type `[[(b, b)]]`.

Comment: It works when I've flatten the list `test = mapTuple myfunc $ concat myTup`. But is there anyway that I can do without flatten the list?

Comment: "It should be `[[(2,2),(3,3)],[(4,4)]]`". "It works when I've flatten the list". Choose one.

Comment: You can't have the same function to work on lists-of-tuples and, at the same time, on lists-of-lists-of-tuple. What do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course your mapTuple won't work when you change the type to `[[(a,a)]]` because `((a1, a2) : xs)` still has the type `[(a,a)]`.

If you want to apply your mapTuple to a list of lists of tuples rather than a list of tuples then you don't need to change mapTuple at all.

Let's look at the types for a second:
mapTuple (before you changed it) had type `(a -> b) -> [(a,a)] -> [(b,b)]`

Partially applying mapTuple to myfunc we get `[(a,a)] -> [(b,b)]`

From the comments you want a function that takes `[[(1,1),(2,2)],[(3,3)]] :: [[(a,a)]]` and returns `[[(2,2),(3,3)],[(4,4)]] :: [[(b,b)]]`

So we want to take this partial function and apply it to every `[(a,a)]` in `[[(a,a)]]` to get `[[(b,b)]]`.

So overall we want a function with type:
`([(a,a)] -> [(b,b)]) -> [[(a,a)]] -> [[(b,b)]]`

This can simplify to `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`. Well there is already a function that does that for us! Regular old map.

So using your old mapTuple with type `(a -> b) -> [(a, a)] -> [(b, b)]`
we get the correct result by the following:

`test = map (mapTuple myfunc) myTup`

Hopefully this makes sense, if not feel free to ask for clarification :)

Comment: This is an accurate and precise answer!!! Yes this really help. I wrote down your explanation on a piece of paper in order to understand it. You nailed this part _"From the comments you want a function that takes `[[(1,1),(2,2)],[(3,3)]] :: [[(a,a)]]` and returns `[[(2,2),(3,3)],[(4,4)]] :: [[(b,b)]]`

So we want to take this partial function and apply it to every `[(a,a)]` in `[[(a,a)]]` to get `[[(b,b)]]`."_ Something new to me is the simplification to `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]` which I think I need to look more into this. It looks like math. This should be a good reference. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a one to one answer to your question. However i have to say that in Haskell a tuple is not an ideal representation of types like  `(a,a)`. A tuple is meant to group different types like `(a,b)`.

Your job basically requires an `fmap` over tuple but `fmap` only effects the second item of the tuple. Then you may create a "new type" from tuple for a new functor instance in which `fmap` would effect both items. But then... you already have that. It's `[]`. So why don't you use `[]` in the place of a tuple which would introduce enormous simplicity if you dive into applicative types?

```
mapNestedList :: (a -> b) -> [[[a, a]]] -> [[b, b]]
mapNestedList f = ((map f <$>) =<<)

Prelude> mapNestedList (+1) [[[1,2],[5,6],[9,19]]]
[[2,3],[6,7],[10,20]]
```

So what's going on here?

- The type of `map (+1)` is `Num a => [a] -> [a]`
- Remembering that `<$>` is in fact inline `fmap`, the type of `(map (+1) <$>)` turns out to be `(Num a, Functor f) => f [a] -> f [a]`
- Which means we have a functor that contains lists and we will apply a function to these lists. This functor can be a `Maybe` type or whatever. In this particular case our functor just happens to be another `[]`.
- Then comes `(=<<)` operator which is in fact the flipped version of monadic bind `(>>=)`. The type of `(=<<)` is `Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b`. As for this type signature and in this particular case, the `a` type variable stands for a type like `Num c => [[c]]` and `b` stands for `Num c => [c]`, yielding `m b` to resolve as `Num c => [[c]]` and `m a` to resolve as `Num c => [[[c]]]`.
- So from above given type variables for the `(a -> m b)` we can use `((map (+1) <$>)` and the final type of `((map (+1) <$>) =<<)` turns out to be `(Num b, Monad m) => m (m [b]) -> m [b]`.

Once again...

```
Prelude> mapNestedList (+1) [[[1,2],[5,6],[9,19]],[[10,20],[30,40]]]
[[2,3],[6,7],[10,20],[11,21],[31,41]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment Redu. Agree on a tuple is not an ideal representation of types like `(a,a)`. And if it is a list like you've suggested, it can be used with the `mapNestedList`.